# Equation in SQL query

Tags: sql

I am trying to identify duplicate data within our database.

If somebodys first seat is 1, and their last seat is 3, it means they should have x3 num_seats

So i want to run a query where first_seat - last_seat +1 = num_seats. Any pointers on what is wrong with my query?

```
select acct_id, event_id, event_name, section_name, row_name, first_seat, last_seat, num_seat
from dba.v_event
where first_seat - last_seat +1 != num_seat
```

Comment: I imagine your SQL server will return an error message with some useful information. Why not look there first?

Comment: What results are you getting? What's wrong with them?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, SQLite? Please correct the question tag to show this.

Comment: If num_seats can be derived from other data, consider eliminating num_seats. It's redundant and error prone. Or maybe that's your intent and you're verifying the assumption?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your equation is backward. It should be `last_seat - first_seat + 1`.

In your example, `first_seat = 1` and `last_seat = 3`.

```
first_seat - last_seat + 1 = 1 - 3 + 1 = -1
last_seat - first-seat + 1 = 3 - 1 + 1 = 3
```

If you want to allow the seats to be listed in either order, you can use `ABS()` to get the absolute value of the difference:

```
ABS(last_seat - first_seat) + 1
```